# Can this wing damage cause a car to run/move noticeably/significantly different?

Tags: aerodynamcs

Sometimes my car seems to not feel straight, drag to the left, whirl around and not feel as peppy as before.   I'm guessing this is due to a needed wheel alignment. However I have been wondering, could the damages to the wing shown below i.e. the panel going inside lead to significant aerodynamic issues such that it could cause car not to go straight, steer to left or have any other noticeable issues?  I imagine these damages wouldnt lead to  any noticeable issues but just want a more informed opinion. Perhaps the air is getting into the car and causing aerodynamic complications.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAOGH.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aerodynamic resistance will be having an effect here, but its unlikely to effect stability at normal road speeds. You will get airflow disturbance around the damaged area causing drag, however as for giving the car a not feeling/travelling straight type symptom.. I believe inspection and maintenance covering wheel alighnment, tyre condition, brakes and suspension areas would be of more help towards identifying the problem your having.

Comment: yep.. you'd probably have to be getting upwards of 100mph before you'd notice any aero effects from that damage.